# upload file using tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

Using Tomcat and Struts 2.

```
public FileAction class
{ 
    ......
    public upload()
    {
        .....   
        String fullFileName = request.getContextPath() + "/productImages/" + filename;
        File theFile = new File(fullFileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(upload, theFile);
        .....
    }
 }
```

The problem is when I upload an image it will not add image in `localhost:8085/shoppingCart/productImages` and also not give any exception.

But when i write `String fullFileName="c:upload/productImages/" + filename;` it will save the file at `c:upload/productImages/` path

mean working normal in `c:upload/productImages/` case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the file uploaded to the server's context, you need to use `ServletContext.getRealPath(...)` to find the base directory of the deployed application. Note that this will *not* work if you're deploying a war file. Uploaded files should go to an absolute location on the server itself.

For downloading an uploaded image you'd write a [stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html) (since you're using Struts 2) and use it to load and stream the uploaded file back to the client.

Comment: but i readed in java documentation that getRealPath(...) is depriciated

Comment: [Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)). In any case, it doesn't matter--you shouldn't be uploading it to the app's directory hierarchy anyway. And you may not even be *able* to. Plus if you redeploy you risk uploaded images being overwritten. Save them elsewhere.